# I am getting Amazon S3 400 Bad request

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

[image]I have deployed my Angular project in AWS S3. When i run the project i am getting following error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

This error is repeating for nearly 290 times and after that index.html is loading.
In angular i put all API url's in api_urls.json file.
I am confused whether problem is with AWS S3 or Angular. Following are my S3 bucket permissions

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::vital-aws-deployment/*"
    }
]}
```

Comment: FWIW, that links is opening just fine in my browser. I'd start investigating from angular side.

Comment: Thank you for the link. but my problem is with AWS S3

Comment: can you paste the permission of your s3 bucket here

Comment: the uploaded objects needs to have public permissions and static webstie option should be enabled

Comment: I have updated my question with bucket permissions @varnit

Comment: permissions look ok to me have you made all the files in s3 bucket public and enabled static site hosting

Comment: Yeah , after making making them public problem went away for some time like 15 minutes. but now it is coming again @varnit

Comment: that is strange did you make it public again ?